# Can't find retweets in my Tweepy stream JSON file

Tags: json, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I am using Tweepy to stream the Twitter API and get all tweets from a specific region. I later analyze the tweets for specific contents. It works perfectly when analyzing extended tweets, regular tweets, and quotes. But I noticed I couldn't analyze retweets. After looking a little further, I noticed my file contained no tweet['retweeted']=="True".

I am wondering the following: a) is it normal that a JSON file created by streaming the Twitter API with tweepy won't contain any retweet? I know that when streaming the retweet counter or favorite counter will always be 0 because that's how it stands when the tweet is posted and tweepy streams it --it also never updates it. Is there something like that for retweets that I'm missing maybe?

If it's not normal that there won't be any retweets when streaming the Twitter API then b) is my Twitter API streamer correct or am I doing something that would exclude retweets from the file?

And c) am I correctly checking the content of retweets in the JSON file with the code that follows? Maybe I'm calling retweets in the wrong way in the code that I use?

For question b), that is the code I use to stream the Twitter API:

```
from credentials import *

auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)

# Creating an interface to the RESTful API
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

#Function to collect tweets
class save_results(tweepy.StreamListener): 

    def on_data(self, data):
        with open('TweetFile.txt', 'a') as f: #that is to save the tweets 
# to a file
            f.write(data)

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        # Disconnect if the policy for number of attempted connections 
#allowed is passed.
        if status_code == 420:
            return False
        else:
            return True
    def on_exception(self, exception):
       print(exception)
       return True

twitter_stream = tweepy.Stream(auth, save_results())

#twitter_stream.filter(track=['Trump'])    

USCan=[-165.5,26.1,-52.7,72.9]

twitter_stream.filter(locations=USCan,async=True)
```

For question c), that is how I check for the content of retweets. Let me note that it works perfectly for extended tweets, regular tweets, and quotes:

```
with open('TweetFile.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            tweet = json.loads(line)
        except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
            pass
        if (('text' in tweet) and ('place' in tweet)):
            if tweet['place'] is not None and tweet['place']['country_code'] is not None:
                if tweet['place']['country_code']=='US':
                    total_tweets_US +=1
                    if (('text' in tweet) and ('place' in tweet)):
                        if tweet['place'] is not None and tweet['place']['country_code'] is not None:
                            if tweet['place']['country_code']=='US':
                                if 'retweeted_status' in tweet and tweet["retweeted_status"]["extended_tweet"]["full_text"] is not None:                                    
                                    if any(s in tweet["status"]["retweeted_status"]["extended_tweet"]["full_text"].lower() for s in keyword1):
                                        if any(t in tweet["status"]["retweeted_status"]["extended_tweet"]["full_text"].lower() for t in keyword2):
                                            extended_retweets +=1
                                            print("Of " + str(total_tweets_US) +" tweets," + str(extended_retweets) +" were extended retweets")
                                else:
                                    if 'retweeted_status' in tweet and tweet['retweeted_status']['text'] is not None:                                    
                                        if any(s in tweet['retweeted_status']['text'].lower() for s in keyword1):
                                            if any(t in tweet['retweeted_status']['text'].lower() for t in keyword2):
                                                retweets +=1
                                                print("Of " + str(total_tweets_US) +" tweets," + str(retweets) +" were retweets")
```

Also for question c), here is how I verify further whether my JSON file has any retweeted tweets in there:

```
with open('TweetFile.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            tweet = json.loads(line)
        except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
            pass
        if (('text' in tweet) and ('place' in tweet)):
            if tweet['place'] is not None and tweet['place']['country_code'] is not None:
                if tweet['place']['country_code']=='US':
                    total_tweets_US +=1
                    if 'text' in tweet and tweet['text'] is not None:
                        if tweet['retweeted']=="True":
                            print("Retweeted!")
```